# How to fix Python import google API error

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
```

After pip installing google api for python google tells me to use this command however the command doesn't work!

Can anyone help?

https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\M1\PycharmProjects\YouTube\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'
```

https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python

Comment: Pycharm will probably give you an option to download your package try downloading through Pycharm it might work better than through pip.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the libraries using the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib
```

Then, you can check that the library has been installed properly by running:

```
pip show google-api-python-client
```

Now, you should be able to import the libraries in your python code. Make sure that the code is executed within your virtual environment in case you are using one.